# Configuring Custom context path the war in the jetty server via Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty

How to configure the custom context root for the war in the jetty server. I have provided the context values in the custom context in the `IntelliJ > Deployment` tab but post that server is not coming up. Please assist.

Adding below `Jetty.xml` for your reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    <Arg name="threadpool"><Ref refid="threadPool"/></Arg>

    <Call name="addBean">
      <Arg><Ref refid="byteBufferPool"/></Arg>
    </Call>

    <Call name="addBean">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler">
          <Arg name="name"><Property name="jetty.scheduler.name"/></Arg>
          <Arg name="daemon" type="boolean"><Property name="jetty.scheduler.daemon" default="false" /></Arg>
          <Arg name="threads" type="int"><Property name="jetty.scheduler.threads" default="-1" /></Arg>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>

 <Call name="addBean">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
        <Set name="name">myrealm</Set>
        <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
        <Set name="hotReload">true</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>


    <New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
      <Set name="secureScheme"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.secureScheme" default="https" /></Set>
      <Set name="securePort"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.securePort" deprecated="jetty.secure.port" default="8443" /></Set>
      <Set name="outputBufferSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.outputBufferSize" deprecated="jetty.output.buffer.size" default="32768" /></Set>
      <Set name="outputAggregationSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.outputAggregationSize" deprecated="jetty.output.aggregation.size" default="8192" /></Set>
      <Set name="requestHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.requestHeaderSize" deprecated="jetty.request.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
      <Set name="responseHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.responseHeaderSize" deprecated="jetty.response.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
      <Set name="sendServerVersion"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.sendServerVersion" deprecated="jetty.send.server.version" default="true" /></Set>
      <Set name="sendDateHeader"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.sendDateHeader" deprecated="jetty.send.date.header" default="false" /></Set>
      <Set name="headerCacheSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.headerCacheSize" default="1024" /></Set>
      <Set name="delayDispatchUntilContent"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.delayDispatchUntilContent" deprecated="jetty.delayDispatchUntilContent" default="true"/></Set>
      <Set name="maxErrorDispatches"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.maxErrorDispatches" default="10"/></Set>
      <Set name="blockingTimeout"><Property deprecated="jetty.httpConfig.blockingTimeout" name="jetty.httpConfig.blockingTimeout.DEPRECATED" default="-1"/></Set>
      <Set name="persistentConnectionsEnabled"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.persistentConnectionsEnabled" default="true"/></Set>
      <Set name="requestCookieCompliance"><Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.CookieCompliance" name="valueOf"><Arg><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.requestCookieCompliance" deprecated="jetty.httpConfig.cookieCompliance" default="RFC6265"/></Arg></Call></Set>
      <Set name="responseCookieCompliance"><Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.CookieCompliance" name="valueOf"><Arg><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.responseCookieCompliance" default="RFC6265"/></Arg></Call></Set>
      <Set name="multiPartFormDataCompliance"><Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.MultiPartFormDataCompliance" name="valueOf"><Arg><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.multiPartFormDataCompliance" default="RFC7578"/></Arg></Call></Set>
    </New>
   <New id="CXOMetadataDatasource" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/CXOMetadataDatasource</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
        <Set name="DriverType">thin</Set>
        <Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@slc16frz.us.oracle.com:1521/pdborcl</Set>
        <Set name="User">dp1mt1_FAWAPPSHELL</Set>
        <Set name="Password">welcome1</Set>
        <Set name="connectionCachingEnabled">true</Set>
        <Set name="connectionCacheProperties">
          <New class="java.util.Properties">
            <Call name="setProperty">
              <Arg>MinLimit</Arg>
              <Arg>5</Arg>
            </Call>
            <!-- put the other properties in here too -->
          </New>
        </Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>  

<New id="FawCommonDatasource" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/FawCommonDatasource</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
        <Set name="DriverType">thin</Set>
        <Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@slc16frz.us.oracle.com:1521/pdborcl</Set>
        <Set name="User">dp1mt1_FAWCOMMON</Set>
        <Set name="Password">welcome1</Set>
        <Set name="connectionCachingEnabled">true</Set>
        <Set name="connectionCacheProperties">
          <New class="java.util.Properties">
            <Call name="setProperty">
              <Arg>MinLimit</Arg>
              <Arg>5</Arg>
            </Call>
            <!-- put the other properties in here too -->
          </New>
        </Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New> 

    <Set name="handler">
      <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
        <Set name="handlers">
         <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
           <Item>
             <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
           </Item>
           <Item>
             <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
           </Item>
         </Array>
        </Set>
      </New>
    </Set>
    
    <Set name="stopAtShutdown"><Property name="jetty.server.stopAtShutdown" default="true"/></Set>
    <Set name="stopTimeout"><Property name="jetty.server.stopTimeout" default="5000"/></Set>
    <Set name="dumpAfterStart"><Property name="jetty.server.dumpAfterStart" deprecated="jetty.dump.start" default="false"/></Set>
    <Set name="dumpBeforeStop"><Property name="jetty.server.dumpBeforeStop" deprecated="jetty.dump.stop" default="false"/></Set>


</Configure>
```

[Screenshot of run-jetty-run IntelliJ plugin popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF2zI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All, This was a bug in the Intellij IDEA, and after having multiple discussions with them. It is fixed and will be part of the likely 2020.2.3 release.

Thanks and see if you can visit the below link :
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-250458?_ga=2.158046906.1073613107.1599818699-1009100717.1597946561

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

The context path is controlled by the bottom of that screenshot.

The "Use Custom Context Root".

You currently have "oaxservice.war" selected, and it's context path is set to `/api/oax`

So that means your server could be accessed from `http://localhost:8080/api/oax`

Select the other war to set it's context path to a different value.

Note: the plugin you are using is not maintained by the Eclipse Jetty project.

Comment: First, thank you for your response. I have already done that but the issue is my jetty is not starting up. Traversing the logs found below. Any suggestion?{"timestamp":"2020-08-26T05:35:13.067Z","levelname":"ERROR","threadName":"Scanner-1","logger":"oracle.biapps.cxo.web","msg":"Exception while getting the context path","context":"default","exc_info":"java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext$Context cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.

Comment: Added jetty.xml for your reference to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have mapped both the artifacts in the deployment tab and provided the custom context path as provided in the screenshot. I am able to launch the application and all seems okay but deployment status is not refreshed to green ticked or deployed successfully. Also when I do manual refresh it says. -"[2020-08-27 04:27:33,489] Artifact Gradle : com.oracle.faw.dp : oaxui.war (exploded): Artifact is not deployed. Press 'Deploy' to start deployment" . Please refer to the screenshot attached.

So it works but deploy status is not refreshed. Still need to figure it out.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isE3c.png)

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the sample project to reproduce attached and the logs. Also include any customizations you've made to Jetty configuration.

Comment: Thank you. I have done that. We wait for their response and update accordingly here.